# AngularJS directive/component parameters: bindings or DOM access?

Tags: angularjs

Consider this general case, in which you have a directive that has to process an input given as a parameter.

What I usually do is something like this:

```
directive(function() {
  scope {
    param: '@'
  },
  bindToController: true,
  link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs, ctrl) {
    process(ctrl.param);
  }
}
```

But I am seeing the following really often:

```
directive(function() {
  link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
    process(iAttrs.param);
  }
}
```

which for some reason looks the "wrong" way to me, despite it works. My thought is that it goes against the Angular philosophy to directly mess about the DOM when you don't need to. Also, the first way your directive implicitly exposes an interface which helps you to validate the inputs, while the second way your directive and the template that uses it will be highly coupled.

For simplicity my example was simple attribute binding here, but the same applies for `'<foo'` or `'=foo'` bindings against interpolating values and processing them by `attrs.foo`.

I haven't found *anything* on the Internet pointing out that one of these practices is incorrect, and I am wondering if it is just me overthinking about what might be just a matter of style preference or it is really conceptually wrong.

If it is just a matter of preference, why is my reasoning wrong then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's does look more *angular* to pass input to a directive through the scope property, but this will also create a new isolated scope behind the scenes. While in most cases this may be desirable, sometimes you need to use two directives on the same html element.

In that case, trying to pass input to the second directive through the scope, you will get the lovely

```
Error: $compile:multidir //and some more info here
```

So you are forced to use attributes, or rethink your approach and try to do whatever you are doing with only one directive.

Bottom line, while it's cleaner to use the scope property and let it perform all the validation, interpolation, etc for you, it's not always possible.